# Powershell and WPF Treeview

Tags: wpf, powershell

I'm  currently working on a powershell tool where I need to create a gui. It seems that according to my needs I would need to use WPF instead of Windows Form. The treeview control in windows forms doesn't let you customize the treeview items. Here is a sample of what I need :

[image]

Basically I would need to add treeviewitems on the fly. According to the nodeLevel, I would need to apply different image and progress bar. I would also need to be able to change the visibility of these controls. And all of these will be accomplished using powershell.

Can someone show me a direction, how should I approach this ? How/where should I start ?

Comment: Google examples of using XAML data templates with TreeView (plenty of existing examples in C#). You may find that you'll need to compile at least 1 .NET class to represent the tree nodes, so I'm not sure you can do this in "pure" powershell

Comment: Hello Mathias
Thank you for your your reply. Actually, after all different examples that I saw by googling; I understand that it will be much better if I use a data templates. Thus yesterday evening, I've started to play around to create a XAML code including a treeview that has a data template. Then I've created a observable collection and added some data in it. Then assign the collection as the datacontext of the treeview. Up to here everything worked fine. But I hit the following 2 issues there:

Comment: 1.The treeview doesn't get refreshed If I add a new Items into observable collection.
2.Currently I could not find a way to assign a CLICK event to a button that is in the template. Unfortunately all suggestions that I came around in the web, uses "$windnow.FindName" way to grab the control and create an even using "ADD_Click"
Unfortunately this way does work on the control that are created/added via XAML and/or runtime; but it doesn't work if the controls are created within a data template.

Any suggestions ?

Comment: Re-assign the DataContext after changing the collection

Comment: Excellent that did the trick. Now my next problem to solve is to find somehow,someway to register a click event to the buttons that are created via Datatemplate.

Comment: Mathias, I would like to assign your answer as reply to my question. But as you have used "comment", I'm not able to assign it as valid answer. Would you be so kind and just copy your first comment and re-post it using answer button down below. Thx

Answer (score 1):

You can use standard XAML for WPF to create window with arbitrary controls, events, styles and so on. Then call `XamlReader.Load()` to create a WPF Window object and `Window.ShowDialog()` to show it.

```
# WPF Window with XAML
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    x:Name="Window" Title="WPF Window from PowerShell" WindowStartupLocation = "CenterScreen" 
    Width = "800" Height = "600" ShowInTaskbar = "True">
<TreeView>
   <TreeViewItem Header="Group 1">
       <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <Image Source="image.png" />
                <TextBlock Text="Level 2.0" />
                <ProgressBar Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Name="Progress" Width="100" IsIndeterminate="True"/>
                <Button>Start</Button>
            </StackPanel>   
       </TreeViewItem>
       <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1"></TreeViewItem>
       <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1"></TreeViewItem>
   </TreeViewItem>
   <TreeViewItem Header="Group 2">
       <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1"></TreeViewItem>
       <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1"></TreeViewItem>
       <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1"></TreeViewItem>
   </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
</Window>
"@ 

$XmlNodeReader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($XmlNodeReader)
$Window.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Hello Mikhail, thank you for your reply. Unfortunately the way that you does not work for me. As it is more static way of doing things. If I want to add/remove more Items to the treeview; then I have to modify the xaml. which is not an option. 
I've also tried to add my items to the tree by creating them on the fly. I've created the stackpanel+Img+txt+progress+button controls and added them to a treeviewItem.Then added the treeviewItem to the treeview. But when the form renders,I see that all the controls that I've created become the subnode of the parent treenode. This approach didn't worked